# How to insert data into table in Spring batch application startup

Tags: spring, initialization, spring-batch, startup

I am new to Spring Batch programming and stucked in following scenario.

I have a Spring Batch application, and I want to run a SQL INSERT script everytime the app starts.

Scenario :

My Spring batch application has 2 databases - (1) HSQL and (2) MySQL
All the tables that are internal to spring batch are created in HSQL and all the tables required for application are present in MySQL. I want to run a INSERT SQL script in MySQL everytime a application starts.

I went through many of the articles, and as suggested in most of the articles created `data.sql` and `data-mysql.sql` and ran my app. But it tries to search the table in HSQL and throws **Object not found exception**.

Is there any way I can execute a SQL script so that it will try to connect to MySQL and then do inserts.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Saurabh

Comment: Is this every time the Spring Batch job starts or the application?  Is it a Spring Boot app or something else?

Comment: @MichaelMinella everytime when app starts

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JobExecutionListener.beforeJob` **Listener** along with  Spring **ScriptUtils**

**Sample Code:**

```
public class MyobListener implements JobExecutionListener {
@Autowired
Private DataSource yourMySQLDataSource 

   //This method will be called before job get started 
    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(yourMySQLDataSource.getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("your.sql"));

    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {   

    }
}
```

**Reference** : [ScriptUtil](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html)